# PrimeFacess read-only attribute is getting disabled sometimes

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have the below xhtml code to make my textarea readonly for the user.

```
<p:inputTextarea id="decisionNotes"
                readonly="#{facesContext.renderResponse}"
                value="#{notesBean.decisionNotes}"
                style="width: 114em;" autoResize="true" widgetVar='textAreaWidget'>
            </p:inputTextarea>
```

It's working 8/10 times perfectly but sometimes randomly the text area becomes writable.

Any idea why this is happening or a better way to disable textarea for manual writes ?

Primefaces-4.0

Comment: Tried PF 5.0, 5.1, 5.2, 5.3, 6.0, 6,1 or 6.2 or even 6.3-SNAPSHOT?

Comment: If the code above is correct then definitely will try this is higher versions. Thanks !

Comment: if it works 8 out of 10 there cannot be fundamentally something wrong. and tried a plain jsf `h:inputTextArea`? Same behaviour? Then it might be JSF version related. Tried a newer version of that?

Comment: And you want it 'conditionally' to be readonly. Readonly explicitly when? (and when not)

Comment: if it's conditional, maybe you got something wrong in your bean. i always use disabled attribute to prevent users to input.